# Tenant wide consent in IdentityServer4

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

We have an instance of IdentityServer4 running and use it internally for our apps. Those app clients have the property `RequireConsent` set to `false`. The result is, you go to the apps website (app1.website), you are redirected to the identity server website (identity.website), where you log in, and redirected back to app1.website.

We also allow 3rd parties to build apps or integrations against our system. In their case, every user needs to approve the app on a consent screen, before they can get the refresh token for that user. There are 2 ways this can play out:

1. The 3rd party has a user management on their own, in that case they only need 1 user who initiates the connection, and this user's token is used for every further interaction with our system.
2. The 3rd party doesn't have their own user management, and instead relies on our identity server to authenticate users. This is something, we want to encourage more in the future, as it helps our partners to build their apps faster, since they don't need to deal with the whole user flow, like confirm email, forgot password, ...

However, the problem in option 2 is, that our app (which is B2B) has a user structure that is similar to slack. When one user in an organization approved an app, others should be able to use it without the need for a consent screen (especially since not all users are allowed to approve apps).

In the current scenario, if the organization owner, Alice, approved the 3rd party app X and told Bob to use it, Bob would still see a consent screen. If Bob were also an organization owner, he could approve the consent screen, but if he were just an intern in the company, he wouldn't be able to use the app X.

What I'd really want is to approve a 3rd party app on an organizational level. In azure active directory, what I'm looking for seems to be called [Tenant Admin Consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/trusted-application-api/docs/tenantadminconsent). There is a similar question [How do I trigger the admin_consent flow using IdentityServer 4 for a multi-tenant app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428091/how-do-i-trigger-the-admin-consent-flow-using-identityserver-4-for-a-multi-tenan?rq=1) - however, We aren't using IdentityServer 4 as a middleman, but it's the final user management instance.

How can I configure / extend IdentityServer4, so that if the second user, from the same organization, tries to use an app, their refresh token will be automatically generated, without a consent screen?

---

**Update:** It's not about replacing Option 1 with Option 2. Big providers will keep their custom user management. But small app providers should be able to re-use our user management features. Once an app is "tenant wide" connected, any user from that tenant should be able to access it, as if the app config was `RequireConsent=false` (other tenants would still need to connect it with a consent screen first)

Comment: I don't think [IdentityServer consent](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/consent.html) is meant for that: _Consent is used to allow an end user to grant a client access to resources_. With or without consent, a user can use any client that is configured in IdentityServer. Seems you are talking about user authorization, which isn't part of IdentityServer. Instead you may want to take a look at the [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/), the recommended tool for user authorization.

Comment: Thx, I guess there are many aspects, which need addressing. What I'm trying to talk about here is an organization wide consent screen, which isn't necessarily bound to a specific user. It gives an application address to resources (APIs governed by scopes) but there's no concept of permissions behind it. Permissions come into play, when users should be prevented from executing actions. Users, not apps. How to tackle that will definitely be another big topic. For now, I'm just focusing on creating an oauth connection to another app for the whole organization and all its users at once.

Comment: With option 1, do you create a user in IdentityServer for that organization that is used by all their users? And with option 2, where is the information of the organization and its users stored? And how is access denied to users that are not part of an organization that has given tenant wide consent? Do you use certain claims?

Comment: Yes, every token has a claim with the tenant ID - so you know which organization the user belongs to. You can fetch more data for the given organization via API with that JWT. In option 1 they usually have a dedicated "app-user" in our system and probably also in the 3rd party app. I've updated my question to make it clearer what I mean

Comment: Not yet. I had to quickly switch to a different task. I'll get back to this next week. Sry