# Azure admin consent workflow and redirect url tenant how to prevent attack?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

After admin grants consent, you get redirected.
Params include tenant but this can be changed by the user. So in case someone replaces tenant id with the id of another customer of my app that has granted admin permissions they would get access to other's data.

Is there any way to prevent this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "they would get access to other's data"? How does your app use the tenant ID parameter of the redirect after admin consent, and why does this result in allowing access to data?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below points can be worked around in your case.

1. The multi tenant application need to be given some permissions-
   delegated and application permissions while registration.
2. Add permissions that require admin consent.Like to see user profile
   of all users, you need admin consent.And don’t grant it when user
   logs .For example ,Don’t grant permission to read all users full profile.(some delegated permissions always require admin consent and make sure those are given carefully)
   And it should be noted that if the app uses only delegated permissions then users really only can access their tenant's data.

[image]

3. As when a user from a different tenant signs in to the application
   for the first time, Azure AD asks them to consent to the permissions
   requested by the application.Application logins after admin granted
   consent can be accessed easily. So while granting  consent, that
   time, admin need to be careful.Then after that the user would only
   be able to access according to the consent given to permissions to
   access.

If the application is targeted for specific tenant only , you can provision the users of Azure AD in your tenant for this app by creating `users and groups` and `assigning roles` to them.

**References:**

1. [Building a multi tenant Azure AD application with roles](https://goodworkaround.com/2019/12/06/building-a-multi-tenant-azure-ad-application-with-roles/)
2. [SO Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428091/how-do-i-trigger-the-admin-consent-flow-using-identityserver-4-for-a-multi-tenan)

---

Since Azure AD will not limit which tenants' users can login to the app if already all permissions are granted, it maybbe helpful if we  implement the checks on the app's side too.
We need to specify the valid token issuers to the token validator ,if you already knew which tenant users are valid to access that particular app .

*Example:*

```js
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // NOTE: We should not turn issuer validation off
        // We should instead list the valid issuers
        // You can find your issuer URI at: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id-here/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
        // It's in the "issuer" property
        NameClaimType = "name",
        ValidIssuers = new[] // THIS IS IMPORTANT Only accept tokens from these tenants
        {
            $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{authSettings.EmployeeTenantId}/v2.0",
            $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{authSettings.PartnerTenantId}/v2.0"
        }
    };
```

Please check  [Best practices for N-tenant Azure AD applications - Joonas W's blog](https://joonasw.net/view/best-practices-for-n-tenant-azure-ad-applications#disqus_thread)

Or
You can select to use only single tenant while registering the application which is for for one or two users only.

**References:**

1. [Single and multi-tenant apps in Azure AD  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps#best-practices-for-multi-tenant-apps)
2. [admin consent workflow  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow)